# Active battery equalizer, max current?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, cell-balancing

I have two 2x12, 50Ah LiFePo4 batteries. Charged via 24V LiFePo4 charger

Max current is 50A (By BMS). Real life: <15A discharge, 5A charge

It is unclear, how to choose the right balancer, by current.
There are some 4A, some 10A. And tiny ones for cells (2A?). How to know, what max current balancer I need? By market offerings, it seems like no >10A balancers. On the other hand, it is in-between cells energy redistribution, outside of the main circuit. Is this max current just limiting how fast the imbalance to be corrected? E.g., lower current balancers cannot work on battery where cells are way different?

Or I have to find/make one for my max current, say, 20-25Amps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a 50 Ah cell, and if balancing is available 100 % of the time, the rule of thumb is that a 50 mA of balancing current is enough. Any BMS can do that. Indeed, I can't think of any BMS that balances at any lower current than that.

[image: Required balancing current]

{Source: Davide Andrea, [Li-ion Batteries and Applications, volume 1 — batteries](http://liionbook.com/), page 212}

Comment: Thank you very much!

I am flattered to receive the answer from the author!